# Adding Akavache Static Linker class or Initializer error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, akavache

I'm currently using **Visual Studio Mac 2019** for to build my **iOs Xamarin Forms** Application.

My Application **Akavache** to store persistent data specifically credentials which I utilizes its **BlobCache.Secure** storage, but sadly the data doesn't persist.

I found that I should add either of the following:
**1. Linker Class**

```
using System;
using Akavache.Sqlite3;

namespace NameSpace.iOS
{
    [Preserve]
    public static class LinkerPreserve
    {
        static LinkerPreserve()
        {
            var persistentName = typeof(SQLitePersistentBlobCache).FullName;
            var encryptedName = typeof(SQLiteEncryptedBlobCache).FullName;
        }
    }

    public class PreserveAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
}
```

or

**2. Initializer**

```
Akavache.Registrations.Start("FollowTheDrop");
```

[Akavache: saved value not available after iOS app restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562027/akavache-saved-value-not-available-after-ios-app-restart)

but every time I add the solution above the following error below occurs during the build

> MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Int32
> SQLitePCL.raw::sqlite3_bind_blob(SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt,System.Int32,System.Byte[])',
> referenced from the method 'System.Void
> Akavache.Sqlite3.BulkInsertSqliteOperation/<>c__DisplayClass7_0::b__0()'
> in 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.1.13.388, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535'.

Am I missing something that causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by updating the following Nuget Packages below which has dependencies on each other:

1. **Akavache 9.0.1**
2. **Splat 14.3.1**
3. **fusillade 2.4.47**

Lastly when adding the linker static class consider adding a Preserve Attribute as shown below:

```
[Preserve]
public static class LinkerPreserve
{
    static LinkerPreserve()
    {
        var persistentName = typeof(SQLitePersistentBlobCache).FullName;
        var encryptedName = typeof(SQLiteEncryptedBlobCache).FullName;
    }
}

public class PreserveAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```